# Check folder's image's extension type and make sure all images are of one format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a project related to computer vision. As I always like to write neat code (even though I have no formal training in coding), I have to resort to asking some questions here. Please bear with me.

There are a few things that I want to achieve with the following function.

One is It checks the extension type, and make sure they are of jpg, jpeg, or png (but this list is customizable).

Two is It checks the image folder and make sure they are of all the same extension type, no surprises like 100 images with '.jpg' while the rest are '.png'.

Lastly, The function should finally return the extension type, so that I can do something like this in my pipeline:

```
image_path = os.path.join(path_to_image, image_id+check_file_type(image_folder_path))
```

> PS: Is there any way to join two strings without using + operator, it
> really looks ugly (but it is just my pet peeve).

My function is as follows, I always feel there is something wrong with it, although it seems to work fine, I would appreciate someone with experience to correct/improve my function and not look cumbersome.

```
from collections import Counter
from tqdm import tqdm
from type import Optional, List

def check_file_type(image_folder_path, allowed_extensions:Optional[List]=None):
    if allowed_extensions is None:
        allowed_extensions = ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg']

    extension_type = []
    file_list = os.listdir(image_folder_path)
    for file in tqdm(file_list):
        extension_type.append(os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower())
    
    extension_dict = Counter(extension_type)
    assert len(extension_dict.keys()) == 1, "The extension in the folder should all be the same, but found {} extensions".format(extension_dict.keys)
    extension_type = list(extension_dict.keys())[0]
    assert extension_type in allowed_extensions
    return extension_type
```

Comment: your code looks good. why do you think your code is not good?

Comment: Because I have no formal training on it, I do not feel confident and wish to seek assurance from better people :)

Comment: One improvement you can do is you can use list comprehension. you can replace middle 4 lines with this `extension_type = [os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower() for file in os.listdir(image_folder_path)]`

Comment: for string question you can use [fstring](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers! Appreciated

Comment: Basically, you want to read all images with given list of extensions (like  ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']) from a given folder and ignore all other images with any other extension??

Comment: @DevashishPrasad basically I want to ensure that. If there are different extensions, the assert will not be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use collections and don't want to iterate over each file in the folder, then you can do something like this.

```
import glob

def check_file_type(image_folder_path, allowed_extensions=None):
    if allowed_extensions is None:
        allowed_extensions = ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg']

    no_files_in_folder = len(glob.glob(image_folder_path+"/*")) 
    extension_type = ""
    no_files_allowed = 0

    for ext in allowed_extensions:
      no_files_allowed = len(glob.glob(image_folder_path+"/*"+ext))
      if no_files_allowed > 0:
        extension_type = ext
        break

    assert no_files_in_folder == no_files_allowed, "The extension in the folder should all be the same, but found more than one extensions"
    return extension_type
```

First get the total number of files you have in the folder

Then get the number of files for each allowed extension, if glob gets more than one file for an extension then loop will break and assert will check that whether no_files_in_folder == no_files_allowed

if true it will return the extension type

if false then surely there are files with more than one extension in that folder

Answer (score 2):

```py
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import os

folder_path = Path.home() / "Desktop"

# Set of allowed extensions
allowed_exts = {".png", ".jpg"}

# Set of extensions present in the directory
extensions_present = {
    Path(i).suffix
        for i in glob.glob(str(folder_path / "*"))
        if Path(i).suffix # do not take empty '' strings.
}

print(extensions_present)
print(extensions_present - allowed_exts)

if len(extensions_present - allowed_exts) > 0:
    print("Unrelated extensions found.")
```

You can construct a set of allowed extensions and then perform set difference to figure out if there are unrelated extensions.